# Ruby error kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ec2/amitools/version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

I dont have any idea about `Ruby`, due to requirement I have to install and configure Ruby. I have made some silly mistake but not able to resolve. Please what can be done to remove following error.

``` /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in ``require': cannot load such file -- ec2/amitools/version ```

Comment: When do you get that error? It basically says one of your applications is trying to use a library you haven't installed yet.

Comment: I am executing the command `# ec2-ami-tools-version` and getting following error
`/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require': cannot load such file -- ec2/amitools/version (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in ``require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/showversion.rb:11:in `<main>'`

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to install the redis database

```
sudo gem install redis
```

Because it is required.

Comment: This fixed the above error for me. However I didn't have a problem configuring Ruby. I was trying to set up a Redis cluster which requires Ruby. And when I ran the command that should start/create the cluster I got the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set both the EC2_AMITOOL_HOME variable as well as the PATH variable. If you do not add the EC2_AMITOOL_HOME directory to your path then you will get this error.

`export EC2_AMITOOL_HOME=/opt/aws/amitools/ec2-1.4.0.9
export PATH=$EC2_AMITOOL_HOME/bin:$PATH`